# Problems with basic proof in modal logic (event based)

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am having trouble deriving the following basic result:

$\ast$) For every $\omega \in \Omega, \omega \in P (\omega),$

from the following axioms:

A1) $K (\Omega) = \Omega$,

A2) $K (A) \cap K (B) = K ( A \cap B)$.

Where, $\Omega$ is a state space, $K: 2^{\Omega} \to 2^{\Omega}$, and  $P (\omega):= \bigcap \{ A \subseteq \Omega \ | \ \omega \in K (A) \}$.

*My attempt was to prove it by contradiction, starting from the definition of $P$, that corresponds to*

$$ \forall A \subseteq \Omega, \omega \in K (A) \Longrightarrow \omega \in P(\omega).$$

*and having that, if $\{ \omega \} \in K (\{ \omega \})$, then $K (\{\omega\} ) = \varnothing$. However I am not going anywhere.*

Any feedback is welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is this modal logic? I don't see any modal operators anywhere. And what is the $P_i$ that appears in the desired conclusion? Your definitions define only a $P$ without subscript. Should the $P:=\cdots$ be $P(\omega):=\cdots$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample to the claim is:

$$ K(A) = \Omega \text{ for all } A$$

Then $P(\omega_0)=\varnothing$ for all $\omega_0$ because it is the intersection of a class that includes $\varnothing$.

---

At first I read the claim as being $\omega\in K(P(\omega))$. But that is not true either; here's a counterexample to that:

- $\Omega$ is infinte.
- $\displaystyle K(A) = \begin{cases} \Omega & \text{if }\Omega\setminus A\text{ is finite} \\ \varnothing & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $

Then $P(\omega_0)=\varnothing$ for all $\omega_0$ because it is the intersection of a class that includes $\Omega\setminus\{\omega\}$ for every $\omega$.

$\omega\in K(P(\omega))$ does hold under the additional assumption that $\Omega$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, you were right about the many typos (I corrected them). Actually, my problem was with the finite case, but I got it.

Comment: @Kolmin: Um, it seems that I misread the claim. It fails even for finite $\Omega$; see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. Actually the claim is not $\omega \in K (P (\omega))$, but $\omega \in P (\omega)$.

Comment: @Kolmin: Yes, I noticed that afterwards. The first part of the edited answer is a counterexample for $\omega\in P(\omega)$.